# I installed Solr for the Search API Solr can someone can give me hints what i could have done wrong?

Tags: 8, search, installation

I'm currently running a CentOS 7 server with cPanel and Drupal 8. I installed Solr 8.8.1 and I can access the administratrion page where I an able to create cores. I installed the *Search API* module with Composer.

When I try to use the Solr server via the *Search API* module, I get a server connection error.

I tried a lot of Drupal configuration, with Basic Auth and standard, via localhost, IP and domain name, but I'm still not able to connect to the Solr server.

Everything I do gets me the following error.

> The Solr server could not be reached or is protected by your service provider.

I am the service provider. I verified the firewall isn't blocking the connection.

Can someone tell me what I could have done wrong?

Comment: Firstly, you have to choose right version seach solr api. As you said, you need to choose version 4.1.

Comment: Hello, i'm currently using the 4.1.12 version of Search API Solr

Comment: That's the module or the actual version of Solr?

Comment: Hello, the version of Solr is mentionned in the original post: 8.8.1

Comment: CentOS may have SELinux enabled by default. See https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

@hotwebmatter's answer above helped me with this issue, so I'll add instructions:

1. Check the status of SELinux: `getenforce`. In my case, the status was `enabled`, so I needed to disable it.
2. Disable SELinux: `sudo nano /etc/selinux/config`, then change `SELINUX=enabled` to `SELINUX=disabled`.
3. Reboot: `systemctl reboot`

Check the status of your Solr server again at `/admin/config/search/search-api/server/scs_solr`.